# Application consistent backup of azure RHEL 7 server

Tags: linux, backup, azure

I've recently deployed several RHEL 7 servers on azure and set up backup jobs in the recovery service. As I understand the service, these backups are filesystem consistent. Unfortunately this is not enough and I need to make the backups application consistent.

Since azure backups are snapshot based, I assume this works similar to the way it does in VMware: By calling a script before and after taking the snapshot. The script is responsible to make the relevant applications flush and halt for the time it takes to make the snapshot.

In fact, I can see the freeze/thaw scripts that are called during the backup and I'm sure I could hack them to add this feature. Of couse, just because I could doesn't mean I should.

So the question remains: How do I make the backup jobs of my linux azure VMs application consistent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Backup released a new feature to ensure application consistency for Linux VMs using pre & post scripts:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-application-consistent-backup-for-linux-vms-using-azure-backup/

Answer (score 0):

At present the only *supported* backup for Linux is file consistent backup.

Hopefully this feature can be added in future updates.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/backup-azure-vms-introduction/